# merge two cell in one single cell in matlab

Tags: matlab

I have two cells. one of them is

```
Cell 1=
'1007_s_at' 780 'DDR1'
'1053_at'   5982    'RFC2'
'117_at'    3310    'HSPA6'
'121_at'    7849    'PAX8'
'1255_g_at' 2978    'GUCA1A'
'1294_at'   7318    'UBA7'
'1316_at'   7067    'THRA'
```

and cell 2=

```
2x1 cell   2x1 cell   2x1 cell
2x1 cell   2x1 cell   2x1 cell
2x1 cell   2x1 cell   2x1 cell
2x1 cell   2x1 cell  2x1 cell
2x1 cell   2x1 cell  2x1 cell
```

I used cat to merge that but I did not get the result that I want:

```
allData= cat(1, cell 1, cell 2);
'1007_s_at' 780 'DDR1'
  '1053_at' 5982    'RFC2'
  '117_at'  3310    'HSPA6'
  '121_at'  7849    'PAX8'
  '1255_g_at'   2978    'GUCA1A'
   2x1 cell   2x1 cell   2x1 cell
   2x1 cell   2x1 cell   2x1 cell
   2x1 cell   2x1 cell   2x1 cell
```

I want the result to display the contents of cell 2 so I can see them in the console, so they are not nested cells.

Comment: Does the order in which the contents of cell 2 appear matter? I would assume you wish to maintain the columns, but aside from that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to do is to change the structure of the `Cell2` cell, so there are no nested cells. This can be done with syntax as: `[Cell2{:,:}]`. However this returns a cell which is `2xn`. In order to make this able to be concatenated to your `Cell1`, we can use the function `reshape`. Therefore all in all:

```
Cell2Expanded = reshape([Cell2{:,:}], [], 3);

>>[Cell1; Cell2Expanded]
ans = 

    '1007_s_at'    [ 780]    'DDR1'  
    '1053_at'      [5982]    'RFC2'  
    '117_at'       [3310]    'HSPA6' 
    '121_at'       [7849]    'PAX8'  
    '1255_g_at'    [2978]    'GUCA1A'
    '1294_at'      [7318]    'UBA7'  
    '1316_at'      [7067]    'THRA'  
    [        1]    [   3]    [     5]
    [        2]    [   4]    [     6]
    [        7]    [   9]    [    11]
    [        8]    [  10]    [    12]
    [       13]    [  15]    [    17]
    [       14]    [  16]    [    18]
```

Which is what you are looking for.